# Dealing with nested tables with EF

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

**Premises:**

1. I have 3 tables in this order: `Company -> Person -> Phone`
2. A `Company` can have multiple `Person` that can have multiple `Phone`.
3. They all have `incremental INT` as `PK`.
4. They have an indentified relationship, so `Phone` have `id_phone` & `id_company` & `id_person` as `PK`.

**Use Case:**

1. User wants to add a `Company` with a `Person` with a `Phone`.

**Problem:**

1. How can I add a `Person` to a `Company` if I don't have the parent's `PK`? (the same happens to `Phone`)

Comment: Assuming you have an instance of `Company` you should be able to just write `myCompany.Persons.Add(myPerson)`

Comment: Yes, I have the instance. It works even if the ID's have a zero?

Comment: Yes, when you save your changes EF will take care of the keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the context will track the additions made the child collections

```
var phone = new Phone() { //whatever };
var person = new Person() { //whatever };
person.Phones.Add(phone);

var company = new Company() { //whatever };
company.People.Add(person);

dbContext.Companies.Add(company);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

As long as you've defined the relationship, it will automatically set the correct foreign keys etc.

Here's an example for code first

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id;
    // other properties
    public virtual Collection<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id;
    // Other properties
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:  you can add additional children in a similar manner, you just have to fetch the entity first

```
var db = new DbContext();
var company = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
if(company != null)
{
    var person = new Person() { // blah };
    company.People.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. For the sake of completeness, you might want to add that you do *not* have to define the primary keys since they are `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Yeah, more of a habit (i tend to only ever use guid keys)

Comment: Adding from scratch works fine, but I can't add another `Person` to a `Company` afterwards. I'm using the `_context.Entry(companyAux).CurrentValues.SetValues(company);`

Comment: added an update that shows how you can add a child to an existing entity.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
company.Persons.Add(new Person
    {
        //set Person properties here but dont worry about PK - EF sorts this out for you
    });
```

you can even do:

```
company.Persons.Addcnew Person
    {
        //set Person properties here but dont worry about PK - EF sorts this out for you
        PhoneNumbers= new PhoneNumber[]
        {
            new PhoneNumber() {/*..*/ }
        }
    });
```